# My Windows 7 option is not listed in GRUB

Tags: grub2, 13.10, windows-7

So this happened to me in July>But, Now I wan my Windows 7 back.Here's exactly what happened.
1)I had my Win7 installed on Drive C and Ubuntu on Drive E.Then I reformatted my Windows 7 and installed it on Drive D.Then I was using Windows 7 and Ubuntu by GRUB.But, One day I thought to give that free Drive C(which I had formatted earlier) space to Ubuntu and did so by Gparted Editor.It was strange that Win7 partition was listed agaist Drive C.However I formatted it as I was knowing that Windows 7 was on Drive D and gave Drive C space to Ubuntu.But, Then I restarted my computer and GRUB was not showing me the option of Windows 7.But still, I can see all my Windows 7 files through Ubuntu in Drive D including `System 32` and all other installed softwares on Windows can be seen.But, I can't switch t Win7 as GRUB doesn't identifies it.Please, If that could be fixed, then please tell me how to do so.

Comment: try "sudo update-grub" in terminal

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the boot options and changing around the boot options? I had and issue a while back where my computer would only boot into windows 7 and the grub was broken and I need to select another boot option to run ubuntu, until I fixed the issue

Comment: can u please elaborate what you are saying? @user252692

Comment: try to see if maybe you need to change around the boot order in the bios, usually f2 or del, sometimes you just need to play around with the order to see if it might be on a different drive. mine for example was booting using the os bootmanager but my linux was stored under the drive labeled notebook harddrive, and I needed to boot from that one, until i fixed the grub screen. It could just be something as simple as the boot order